# PCD files, VFH files and 3D Recognition

Tags: ros, pcd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I was wondering if there was a way to combine several [VFH signatures](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/vfh_estimation.php#vfh-estimation) into one generalized model of a particular object?
Furthermore, is there a way reconstruct a point cloud from a VFH Signature? i.e. If I did have a generalized VFH signature of a particular object, could I then observe what this might look like in the pcd_viewer or something.

Kind Regards,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43648/pcd-files,-vfh-files-and-3d-recognition/) by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Martin,
if I understand correctly by "combine several VFH signatures" you actually mean that you are looking for a way to classify objects using VFH descriptor, right? There is a neat and simple tutorial demonstrating exactly this: http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/vfh_recognition.php#vfh-recognition.

pcd_viewer from PCL knows histograms and can display them.

D.

---

Originally posted by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) with karma: 1420 on 2012-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2012-09-12**:
Hey Dejanpan. Yea I am looking to use them as a classifier, but I was hoping to use only a minimal amount of these signatures. In the tutorial they use several VFH signatures of the same object at different angles, I'd like to use several different types of cups to classify a generic cup, for eg.

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2012-09-12**:
Hey Dejanpan,

**Comment by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on 2017-03-13**:
I think it is possible because most of those cups will have similar signatures,
by the way, is pcl_viewer not pcd_viewer